# Hibernate 5: how to ignore naming strategy for @Column?

Tags: annotations, migration, hibernate-5

Our project will update to Hibernate 5. We have some databases that are controlled by a 3rd party.

Before Hibernate 5, we used `ImprovedNamingStrategy`'s entity's property ignore strategy if annotation `@Column(name="xxxxxx")`. `xxxxxx` maps to the database name.

However, In Hibernate 5, `PhysicalNamingStrategy` will apply strategy on all logical column name, ignoring the annotation. Hibernate 5 should view  `xxxxxx` as logical column name.

Is there a way to make Hibernate 5 ignore apply strategy on annotated properties?

Answer (score 0):

If you configure Hibernate to use `PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl` it should work as expected, i.e. `@Column(name="xxxx")` annotations take precedence.

```
hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: it doesn't, actually